# shifting numbers in python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please help I have no idea on how to write this function. I tried a ceaser cypher function and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Write a function cycle( S, n ) that takes in a string S of '0's and '1's and an integer n and returns the a string in which S has shifted its last character to the initial position n times. For example, cycle('1110110000', 2) would return '0011101100'.

Comment: Hint: if `s = '1110110000'`, what is `s[:-2]` and what is `s[-2:]` ?

Comment: The google search terms you're looking for are "string slicing".

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is:

```
def cycle(s, n):
    return s[-n:] + s[:-n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's `deque` data type as follows:

```
import collections

def cycle(s, n):
    d = collections.deque(s)
    d.rotate(n)
    return "".join(d)

print cycle('1110110000', 2)
```

This would display:

```
0011101100
```